# Spring boot, security Cors configuration problem: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm coding a api in spring boot and spring security that is accessed by a react front-end, the get methods are working good. But when it comes to posts where we have a options as preflight It is returning 401 http status. As I am developing, for now I just want that cors don't block anything. This error don't occur on Insomnia or postman, where I can do the requests without this error. The main endpoint that this error is occouring is /oauth/token, that is the deafault endpoint of spring boot to get the Bearer token, the post that I send there by the react app is given this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

My spring configurations:

WebConfig

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS",  "HEAD", "TRACE", "CONNECT");
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

After doing some searches I think that is cors or some permission that I am not given, but other approaches will be consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK in order for CORS to be properly configured you also need to specify the allowed origins, headers and other stuff if applicable for your use case.
So your CORS mapping would become:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS") //or whichever methods you want to allow
                .allowedOrigins("*") //or www.example.com if you want to be more specific
                .allowedHeaders("Content_Type", "Authorization"); //i also put Authorization since i saw you probably want to do so
    }
```

Check [this picture](https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png), maybe it makes you understand better how it works.

Comment: Ok, and if for now i want to allow all headers can I put ("*")?

Comment: @IgorFroehner, as per the documentation of `allowedHeaders()` method, yes - " * " can be used to allow all headers. Moreover, by default all headers are allowed. 
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html#allowedHeaders-java.lang.String...-

Comment: @IgorFroehner, if this solved your issue i would appreciate upvoting/accepting it as the answer